# Implement fragment tabhost with custom listview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I am trying to implement the fragment tabhost but I do not understande whats the problem here while implementing it. Here is the code below

ListTab.java

```
public class ListTab extends FragmentActivity {
    // Fragment TabHost as mTabHost
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_activity);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(ListTab.this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Today's Deal"),
        TabFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Upcomming Deal"),
            TabFragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

TabFragment.java

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment  {
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment, container, false);
        return V;
    } 

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v(TAG, "Initializing sounds...");
        DBHelper dbhelper=new DBHelper(getActivity()); 
        View v = getView();
        final ListView listview=(ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);  
        final ArrayList<Items> list=new ArrayList<Items>();  
        ArrayList<Items> itemlist= dbhelper.getAllItem();  
        Log.v("Query Check", "Working");
        for(Items item : itemlist){
            //item.getName();
            Log.v("Get_FragmentName:", item.getName());
            item.getDetail();
            Log.v("Get_FragmentDetail:", item.getDetail());
            item.getPrice();
            Log.v("Get_FragmentPrice:", String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));
            item.getEndDate();
            Log.v("Get_FragmentEndDate:", item.getEndDate());
            item.getStartDate();
            Log.v("Get_FragmentStartDate:", item.getStartDate());
            item.getImage();
            list.add(item);
            ItemAdapter adapter=new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), list);  
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

tab_activity.xml

```
  <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
     android:layout_height="80dp">

   <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
     android:layout_height="80dp">

   <TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"/>

   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"/>

   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
   </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

this is the fragment layout tab_fragment.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    tools:context=".DeviceFragment" >

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" /> 
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: listview is not showing.....just tab is there

Comment: post fragment xml also plz, also check if dbHelper.getAllItem() returning any item?

Comment: fragment xml is posted plz look tab_activity.xml....secondly, dbhelper is returning data correctly i have checked its log

Comment: "No tab known for tag null" this is error in tab_activity.xml

Answer (score 0):

For the error: "No tab known for tag null", please give some unique tag name in following line of code:

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Today's Deal"), TabFragment.class, TAG);
```

Where **TAG** can be "TAB1" or any string associated with this fragment only.

- From your xml + Activity code:

  mTabHost.setup(ListTab.this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.**tabcontent**);

  < FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/**tabcontent**"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      **android:layout_weight=**"**0**"/>

This is the problem i see, 0 weight is assigned, it is not giving any width or height to tabcontent.